# how to show hd qualites in jw player

Tags: javascript, php

how to show hd button in jwplayer to my live channel look at images

[and i want to add hd and qualities like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsQs3.png)

here my code

```
var jplayer = jwplayer("container2").setup({

    image: "logo.jpg",
    file: "rtmp://46.43.64.162:1935/pbc/pbc",
    rtmp: {
        subscribe: true
    },
    title: "" ,
    abouttext: "",
    width: '50%',
    height: '400',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    logo: { file: '', margin: 2, position: 'top-left',}
});
```

Comment: This question is neither about javascript nor PHP. This question is about some product/plugin isnt it?

Comment: Do you actually have the video in various renderings like 480p, 720p, 1080p?

Comment: @Bonatti i know that , but how to add that if it a plugin or product 

thanks

Comment: @AxelAmthor no i dont , i was trying other link of live channel , can you give me an example to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you have different RTMP streams for different bitrates, you can reference them all into one SMIL and embed that into the player. When you do that, the HD menu will automatically appear and let the user choose between the available bandwidths.

Source: [JW Player - Dynamic RTMP Streaming](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430398-dynamic-rtmp-streaming)